# Xbox One friends and Xbox Live Gold friends

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network, xbox-game-pass

I switched from the Xbox 360 to Xbox One X so now I pay for Xbox Gamepass Ultimate which I know includes Xbox Live Gold, but why don't my friends from Xbox One transfer to my backwards compatible 360? They use same gamertag, but I have to refriend them on any Xbox Live Gold game.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using same gamertag?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the support page [here](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/friends-social-activity/friends-groups/view-xbox-one-friends-on-xbox-360) this is the expected behavior of the friend list across the platforms. If you want to play with them on **Xbox 360** (or inside the *"emulation"* of Xbox 360 in Xbox One X) you will have to **add them again there** even if they are visible on **Xbox One X**. This is probably a platform limitation.

Comment: You're misreading the question. OP have upgraded their console from Xbox 360 to Xbox One X, not downgrading. By the way, your source also explained that 360's friend should be visible on One. Another reason to doubt that OP is using wrong or new gamertag. Quot: "**When you sign in to an Xbox One console, your Xbox 360 friends will automatically appear in your friends list, as well as in your followers list.**"

Comment: In Xbox One the Xbox 360 backwards compatible games are _"emulated"_ inside Xbox One so the interface (and i guess) the friends functionality works as if you were playing on the actual Xbox 360. That's why from the Xbox One operating system / interface you can see the old friends but from inside the emulation not.